# When did weekly sermons become part of the rabbi's job?

Tags: minhag, history, rabbis, synagogue

Each year on Shabbat Hagadol (the Shabbat just prior to Pesach), our shul rabbi explains that the reason it is called "Shabbat Hagadol" is that it means "The Shabbat of the *Gadol*" ("The great one"). It is a reference to the "gadol" or the rav of the community or congregation.

My rav explained that originally, the rav delivered a sermon only twice yearly - on Shabbat Hagadol and Shabbat Shuva (Shabbat between Rosh Hashanna and Yom Kippur.) He did not deliver weekly sermons as is quite common in shuls, currently.

My question is when and why did the original custom change?

Comment: Actually Rashi is quoted by his students as saying it was called shabbos hagadol because the drasha from the rabbi made the shabbos seem like it lasted for a very long time! True story.

Comment: see http://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/sh/sh3/1/429/index.htm and http://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/sh/sh5/6/1/14.htm

Comment: Is this on-topic? I can’t decide whether this is Jews not Judaism.

Comment: @DonielF The rabbi is a Jew (I think. Plenty of fake ones, out there!) Giving Shabbat sermons is Judaism.

Comment: @DanF Like I said, I wasn’t sure whether this would qualify - thus, I didn’t vote.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/73466/8775.

Comment: A possible duplicate of the question @mevaqesh linked to.

Comment: @user6591 do you have any sources please?

Comment: @Jon it's in the machzor vitri

Comment: @user6591 Thanks.  I found 259 in the link as his explanation for שבת הגדול but he does not quote Rashi as you say?  Is there another place?  http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9377&st=&pgnum=430&hilite=

Comment: @Jon Ok. I see. I was quite certain that's where I saw it. I'll have to get back to you.

Comment: @Jon ok found it here in sefer hapardes. http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=8962&st=&pgnum=367&hilite=

Comment: I'd heard it was heavily influenced because American Protestant churches did so...

Answer (score 4):

Rashi on the Gemorah in Gittin on 38b ד"ה בעידן בי מדרשא says that a chacham used to give a drasha Shabbos (friday) night.

Comment: gemara brachot, its called calla. the gemara speeks about shedim in synagogue. mishna shabbat about kitve kodesh which are prohibited because if the drasha in shabbat

Comment: @kouty I'm confused regarding what your comment adds to the answer.

Comment: @DanF He’s quoting other Gemaras that discuss Shabbos derashos. I believe that Shabbos Kalla was done specifically before Yamim Tovim, however; the reference to sheidim is that in the Shabbos Kalla the place feels packed because of the sheidim, even when there’s plenty of room between each person. I have not learned the one in Shabbos, so I can’t elaborate on that.